# Yii2. Бесконечная глубина вложенности страниц

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Ситуация такая. Имеется некая модель, назовём её Data. Каждый объект этой модели может иметь или не иметь родительский элемент (родитель тоже является экземпляром этой же модели). В итоге, мы можем получать сколь угодно длинные цепочки вида root->child1->child2->...->childN.

Требуется сделать так, что бы у каждого объекта $dataObject была своя страница, при чем url этой страницы должен содержать в себе всех родителей, то есть выглядеть примерно так: site.com/parent1/parent2/.../parentN/data_object. Как правильно это реализовать в UrlManager? Как правильно генерировать ссылки на такие страницы?(конечно же, action и view-файл у всех объектов предполагается общий, вне зависимости от уровня вложенности).

Comment: url напрявляет в action контроллера. а тот в свою очередь создает модель, затем модель что делает и результаты выводятся на экран. на мой взгляд вы не разобрались что такое паттерн MVC. модель - это логика работы с данными, там не должно быть ничего связанного с urlом и html-выводом

Comment: @perfect , я понимаю, что такое MVC, возможно я просто написал несколько некорректно. Я поясню свои мысли. Есть некая модель, например "Post". Кроме того, есть страница, на которой выводится текст конкретного поста, заголовок, дата публикации и т.п. Этой странице соответствует некий action 
(например, actionView контроллера PostController). И, конечно же, должен быть некий url, который направляет нас в этот action. Так вот, я хочу что бы этот url был не такого вида - "site.com/post/view/12", а несколько более сложного (его я описал в тексте вопроса). Надеюсь, больше не возникнет недопонимания.

Comment: По идее, надо кастомный URL rules писать.

Comment: @SamDark речь вот об этом? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#creating-rules

Comment: Да. Именно об этом.

Comment: @SamDark, спасибо, буду пробовать.